# How to match sub strings in non western languages in GAE's search API

Tags: google-app-engine

I have some documents that contain Chinese strings, and trying to make them searchable.
Sadly I get no matched results unless my query keyword is strictly equal to some field's value.
For example here is a snapshot of my SDK console

[image]

I am aiming at the strings in red frame.
If I query with "许巍的歌", I get all 3 items.
However if I query with "许巍", I get nothing.

Specifying field language with "zh" does not help.
It seems Tokenizing service is not working well.

My code is innocent because I am doing the experiments in console prompt.
How could I make any improvements? Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

After deployed my programs I figured out it was the problem of SDK. Substring match works very well in product environment.